# Fetch IPs and Ports from text

Tags: bash, grep

Here is a text:

```
> > <tbody><tr><td>35.41.62.175</td><td>10200</td><td>US</td><td>Swaziland</td><td>Socks4</td><td>Anonymous</td><td>Yes</td><td>24 seconds ago</td></tr>
>
> <tr><td>243.26.5.23</td><td>48111</td><td>US</td><td>Country
> 1</td><td>Socks5</td><td>Transparent</td><td>Yes</td><td>24 seconds
> ago</td></tr>
> 
> <tr><td>167.21.14.161</td><td>10200</td><td>US</td><td>Country
> 4</td><td>Socks4</td><td>Anonymous</td><td>Yes</td><td>24 seconds
> ago</td></tr>
> 
> <tr><td>217.115.2.24</td><td>48111</td><td>RU</td><td>Country
> 5</td><td>Socks5</td><td>Any</td><td>Yes</td><td>24 seconds
> ago</td></tr>
> 
> <tr><td>80.191.90.188</td><td>8181</td><td>UA</td><td>Country
> 6</td><td>Socks5</td><td>Anonymous</td><td>Yes</td><td>1 hour
> ago</td></tr>
> 
> <tr><td>80.191.90.188</td><td>8181</td><td>UA</td><td>Country
> 6</td><td>Socks5</td><td>Anonymous</td><td>Yes</td><td>45 seconds
> ago</td></tr>
> 
> <tr><td>180.161.0.55</td><td>8181</td><td>UA</td><td>Country
> 6</td><td>Socks5</td><td>Anonymous</td><td>Yes</td><td>3 minutes
> ago</td></tr>
```

I would like to extract IPs and the corresponding ports under the following conditions: 
    -

- all countries, except Swaziland or Unknown

  - should be Anonymous
  - should be Socks5
  - should less than 1 hour (or 59 minutes at most)

So the result should be the following

- 80.191.90.188 8181

  180.161.0.55 8181

What I could do so far:

> egrep -vi 'unknown|swaziland|hour' index.html | egrep -i socks5 | grep -i anonymous | grep -oP "(?<=\\)[^<]*" => for the ip

no idea regarding how to fetch the port

your would be greatly appreciated folks !!!!

Comment: `grep` is not native windows command.Is the text really starts with `>` on each line.Is there a chance to had the valid HTML/XML file?

Comment: sorry for the lat part, it should be: grep -oP "(?<=\<tr\>\<td\>)[^<]*"

Comment: it's linux; all I found is working fine, I just need to remove </td><td> between the ip and the port.

Comment: rather you need bash script than a batch one

Comment: Do all of your lines REALLY start with `> ` or is that a remnant of a previous iteration of your attempt to post your input or something? If the posted input isn't what your real input looks like then [edit] your question to fix it or you're going to get an answer that either doesn't work for your real input or is more complicated than it has to be.

Answer (score 0):

An AWK solution:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {RS="> (\n|> )"; FS="</*t[rd]></*t[rd]>"} $4!~/Swaziland|Unknown/ && $7~/Anonymous/ && $6~/Socks5/{print $2,$3}' test.in
80.191.90.188 8181
80.191.90.188 8181
180.161.0.55 8181
```

Comment: Hi James your solution seems interesting; the thing is that I do not know awk; when I apply your solution to the sample I gave, here is what I have: $: command not found

Comment: could you please give more details about BEGIN  RS="> (\n|> )";

Comment: `BEGIN {}` section is only executed in the very beginning and this case it is only used to set the `RS` variable, record separator (think of it as a line in this case) , to \n (enter) or "> ". `FS` or field separator (think of field as a column) is set to any pair of `<td><tr>` to print out only the data between the tags. $4 is is the fourth field (column).

Comment: You should mention it's gawk-specific due to multi-char RS. Other awks will set RS to the first char, `>`, and ignore the rest.